# BlueTooth read service w/ CodenameOne

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate over Bluetooth to a pedometer.  When getting the service info, I receive:

```
  {
  "status":"discovered",
  "address":"f9:F1:50:A5:20:D2",
  "name":"StegTk000606",
  "services":[
    {
     "characteristics": [
        {
            "properties": { "notify":true,"read":true},
            "permissions": {},
            "descriptor":[ {
                    "permissions":{},
                    "uuid":"2902"
                }],
            "uuid":"2a19"
        }],
    "uuid":"180f"
   },
  ...
```

The above, according to the documentation, is the "get battery level" service.  I'm using the CodeoneOne library which is based on Cordova, https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#read, which requires the address, service uuid, and characterstic uuid.  In the above there are 3 uuids.  I'm new to Bluetooth comms, but my understanding is that the call would be -

```
ble.read(callbackMethod, "f9:F1:50:A5:20:D2", "180f", "2a19");
```

However, when I make the call to the chip, it returns with a message "Service not found".

I have been able to connect to the chip with the Cordova connect method, and this works without error.

Am I using the correct uuid? Is the address incorrectly formatted?

Comment: After looking at the Cordova link you have provided seems like you are sending wrong parameters to read method please recheck. It expects success callback, failure callback and params json object with details of address, service uuid and characteristic uuid

Comment: The call above is part of the CodenameOne platform (https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone) so the calls are slightly different as they are Java not JavaScript.